# how to use join with Sqlite Index

Tags: sqlite, join, indexing

I am creating a app with ionic 3. In the app I added a search filter which filter users according to their role. I have 5 tables from which I have to pull the data.In term to do so, I did these steps..

created each table index with the required data.

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS AccountIndexTable ON Accounts(id,roleId,firstName,lastName,email,accountId);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS AddressIndexTable ON Addresses(id,addressTypeId,street,city,state,country,pincode,accountId)
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS CompanyIndexTable ON Companies(id,name,accountId)
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS CommunicationIndexTable ON Communications(id,phone,accountId)
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS OptionalInfoIndexTable ON CustomerOptionalInfos(id,customerType,accountId)
```

and then i used join to get data. Before that I have questions

1: Do I need to use the indexed table in my join?

the Join query:

```
SELECT Accounts.accountId AS accountID,
   Accounts.roleId AS roleID,
   Accounts.email AS email,
   Accounts.firstName || " " || Accounts.lastName AS name,
   Addresses.street AS street,
   Addresses.city AS city,
   Addresses.state AS state,
   Addresses.country AS country,
   Addresses.pincode AS pincode,
   Communications.phone AS phone,
   Companies.name AS compName,
   CustomerOptionalInfos.customerType AS cType
FROM Accounts
LEFT JOIN Addresses ON Addresses.accountId=Accounts.accountId
AND Addresses.addressTypeId=1
LEFT JOIN Communications ON Communications.accountId=Accounts.accountId
LEFT JOIN Companies ON Companies.accountId=Accounts.accountId
LEFT JOIN CustomerOptionalInfos ON CustomerOptionalInfos.accountId=Accounts.accountId
WHERE 1=1
  AND Accounts.isDelete!='true'
  AND Accounts.firstName!= ''
  AND Accounts.roleId = 5
ORDER BY Accounts.firstName ASC
LIMIT ?,?
```

It still takes +2 seconds to execute. Please suggest me the better way of doing this. I have a large number of data.

Comment: I doubt any of those indexes are being used (But check [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) to be sure) except maybe the AccountsIndexTable one, because you're joining on the various table's `accountId` columns but that's not the first one in those indexes. See https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html for details about how sqlite uses indexes and why the order of columns matters.

Comment: every index  is being used. the problem is the loading time.